# Convert Apache configuration to Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to improve the installation documentation of some open source software, but I've hit a snag with the web server configuration. I have this software working well with Apache, but I need to use Nginx in the documentation for consistency. How can I get the same results in Nginx with this Apache configuration?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/publisher/public

        <Directory /var/www/publisher/public>
                AllowOverride None
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://example2.com

                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    Options -MultiViews
                    RewriteEngine On
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
                </IfModule>
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this documentation page to get the correct base configuration for Nginx, as this particular project uses Symfony:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

As noted there, I needed to set fastcgi_pass to 127.0.0.1:9000 to match my PHP-FPM config.

Answer (score 1):

You can use online tools like for the quick convert

- https://winginx.com/en/htaccess
- https://htaccess2nginx.toolpie.com

still, you need to look for missing keys, here is a basic convert:

```
server_name example.com;
root /var/www/publisher/public;
error_log ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log;

location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using the first online tool you linked before posting this question. My configuration is the same as the one in your answer, and it fixed the internal server error I was getting, but now I get a 403 forbidden error. I checked the folder permissions and made sure it was public. Any idea what that could be? Or is it not related to the configuration at all?

Comment: 403 can be result of all sort of things just do a quick review on this article hopefully it will help you
https://www.ionos.com/community/server-cloud-infrastructure/nginx/solve-an-nginx-403-forbidden-error/